# Angular.js view - display a description from a code-description json

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have list of schools each with a code for a school level instead of ES, MS, HM.

```
[
{
"nameOfInstitution": "Summer Elementary",
"schoolLevel": "01304"
},
{
"nameOfInstitution": "Grady Middle",
"schoolLevel": "02400"
}
]
```

I am planning to use another JSON to get the description of those codes from:

```
{
"schoolLevel": [
    {"01302": "All levels"},
    {"01304": "Elementary"},
    {"02400": "Middle"},
    {"02402": "High school"}
    ]
}
```

What is the proper way to display this in Angular in a view where it would look like?

```
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    <p ng-repeat="school in schools">{{school.nameOfInstitution}} - {{school.schoolLevel}}</p>
  </div>
```

Should it 1). iterate through the main JSON and insert the description after "schoolLevel" or 2). should I use a look-up method to find out the description each time I display a school?

I would think the first option is the better choice, but can anyone share some snippets of code on how to best achieve that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a filter for lookup:-

DATA:-

```
 $scope.schools=[
{
"nameOfInstitution": "Summer Elementary",
"schoolLevel": "01304"
},
{
"nameOfInstitution": "Grady Middle",
"schoolLevel": "02400"
}
];

$scope.schoollevel={
"schoolLevel": [
    {"01302": "All levels"},
    {"01304": "Elementary"},
    {"02400": "Middle"},
    {"02402": "High school"}
    ]
}
```

Filter:-

```
app.filter('level',function(){
  return function(item,filter){
    //console.log(item.schoolLevel);
    var levelVal;
    item.schoolLevel.forEach(function(level){
      if(typeof level[filter]!='undefined'){
        console.log(level[filter]);
       levelVal=level[filter];
      }
    }
    );
        return levelVal;  
  }
});
```

HTML:-

```
<p ng-repeat="school in schools">{{school.nameOfInstitution}} - 
    {{schoollevel|level:school.schoolLevel }}</p>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hS4X9KMUFPjg08ZG1OmX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

Below code should work

**Markup**

```
  <div class="item item-text-wrap">
    <p ng-repeat="school in schools">{{school.nameOfInstitution}} - 
    {{level.schoolLevel | filter: school.schoolLevel : true }}</p>
  </div>
```

**Code**

```
$scope.level = {
"schoolLevel": [
    {"01302": "All levels"},
    {"01304": "Elementary"},
    {"02400": "Middle"},
    {"02402": "High school"}
    ]
}
```